# Average of columns of feature matrix to get gist of passage in word2vec?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, word2vec

Word2vec gives me a NxK matrix, where N is the number words in the vocabulary, and K is the number of features. Let's say that I have all the words in my vocabulary mapped to features. I have a passage that has 100 words (Let's assume that everyone of those words is in my vocabulary), I can create a 100 X K matrix, the represent features of the passage, would taking an average along columns, which results in 100 X 1 matrix give me a reasonable summary of the passage?

My end goals is to be able to compare passages. If my above approach is valid, then finding similarity between passages should be trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not recommend such approach. It might fail due to canceling effects between words. Also, the words in your sentence might have different status (i.e., importance) from each other. Hence, merely averaging the word vectors can be risky.

Alternatives to the method you have suggested are

1. Paragraph Vectors. Create a [**dov2vec**](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v32/le14.pdf) model and create paragraph vectors (in your case, passage vectors)
2. [**Geometry of sentences**](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.05358.pdf). Assign weights to each word and weight-average them. It is shown that GloVe performs better than word2vec in this task.